# How do I make certain fields in my ASP.NET MVC model read-only and auto-populate them during entry creation as well as add user role restriction?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, authorization, display

I want to make in some changes in a model and I don't know how. Let me explain. I am using an ASP.NET MVC web app (written in C#)

I have a model with some fields and I display them in an array (the one that you get if you scaffold).

The code is pretty much like the template except some minor changes I've made on other areas to add identity, I scaffolded again with my Entry.cs Model that has some values like these :

```
public int Id { get; set; } // unique entry Id

[Display(Name = "Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DevDate { get; set; } // Date of upload

[Display(Name = "Developer")]
public string dev_name { get; set; } 

[Display(Name = "Project")]
public string impl { get; set; } // implementation

[Display(Name = "Ver")]
public string version { get; set; } // apps version
```

My requests are the following :
i)I want the field Date to be read-only and when a new entry is created the current date and time to be added automatically.
ii) I want the Dev_name also to be added automatically and being read only. I want there to be the user's name
iii) There are other fields in the class but I didn't copy them to be quick. I want users with role X , Admin to be able to edit the first 4 ( except date and name) and users with roles Y, Admin to be able to alter the rest (except the read-only ones).

I am not snipping any other code because I feel it isn't necessary due to the fact that you can get it by scaffolding. Thanks in advance